# h5validate how to require repeated password

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I require to value of `pass` field be equal to `pass2` using h5validate library? I found this https://github.com/dilvie/h5Validate/issues/17 but I still don't understand that, and there is not any example code available.

This:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $.h5Validate.addPatterns({
  pass2: $('#pass').val()
});         

$('form').h5Validate({
  errorClass:'invalid'                  
});

});
```

doesn't work (I have both name and id attribute set to pass and pass2 for inputs of course).

Edit: I tried this:

```
$('#pass').change(function(){
  $('#pass2').attr('pattern', $('#pass').val());
});
```

before calling h5validate, and it does work, but when I put single dot it is obviously interpreted as regex so I can put any char in pass2 field.

I just found this https://stackoverflow.com/a/2593661/627334

But still

```
$('#pass2').attr('pattern', $('#pass').val().replace(/([.?*+^$[\]\\(){}|-])/g, "\\$1"))
```

looks like overkill

Comment: I agree, this looks like overkill. Imagine yourself having to look at and understand this code six months from now. For me, at this point I would look for a different validation solution.

Answer (score 0):

It looks more readable if you extract regex quoting to a function:

```
RegExp.quote = function(str) {
    return (str+'').replace(/([.?*+^$[\]\\(){}|-])/g, "\\$1");
};

...

$('#pass2').attr('pattern', RegExp.quote($('#pass').val()));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var escapeRegex = function (value) {
        return value.replace(/[\-\[\]{}()*+?.,\\\^$|#\s]/g, "\\$&");
    };

    $('#password').blur(function (e) {
        $('#confirm-password').attr('pattern', escapeRegex($('#password').val()));
    });

    $("#submitButton").on("click", function (e) {
        var isValid = $('#passwordForm').h5Validate('allValid');
        if (isValid) {
           console.log('Valid');
        } else {
           console.log('Not Valid');
        }
    });
});

[http://jsfiddle.net/vijay_porwal_mca/fke00v23/][1]
```